# Attempting to change views on click of button

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm testing out a new layout and I need to show a new layout when a button is clicked from MainActivity. I've Googled and tried every answer, however, every piece of code ends up causing the app to crash. Currently, I'm experiencing an issue where it cannot resolve symbol `view`.

Any thoughts? Your help is much appreciated. Here's my code:

```
package com.example.consumer.example;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        button.setOnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            };
        };

    }

}
```

My crash log is the following (from Logcat):

```
01-09 21:40:40.787 7001-7001/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-09 21:40:40.847 7006-7006/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-09 21:40:40.847 7006-7006/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-09 21:40:41.196 7022-7022/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-09 21:40:41.196 7022-7022/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-09 21:41:04.597 6950-6965/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 6965: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
01-09 21:41:04.620 6950-6950/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.surrrge.consumer.surrrge, PID: 6950
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(110327008bytes) bitmap.
                                                     at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:260)
                                                     at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1415)
                                                     at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:545)
                                                     at android.view.View.getDrawableRenderNode(View.java:17314)
                                                     at android.view.View.drawBackground(View.java:17250)
                                                     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17062)
                                                     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16053)
                                                     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16837)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
                                                     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16048)
                                                     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16837)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
                                                     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16048)
                                                     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16837)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
                                                     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16048)
                                                     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16837)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
                                                     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16048)
                                                     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16837)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
                                                     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17074)
                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:751)
                                                     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16053)
                                                     at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:656)
                                                     at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:662)
                                                     at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:770)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2796)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2604)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2211)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
01-09 21:41:05.021 1519-4976/system_process E/EGL_emulation: tid 4976: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
01-09 21:41:05.421 1994-2204/com.android.launcher3 E/EGL_emulation: tid 2204: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
01-09 21:42:46.053 1519-1875/system_process E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 104)
01-09 21:42:46.059 1519-1875/system_process E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 108)
```

Comment: post your crash log from logcat

Comment: @DrilonBlakqori New to Android development so I need to track down how to use logcat. 5 min please.

Comment: Crash log posted to original answer (updated)

Comment: It says Canvas bitmap is large, do post the code for `DisplayListCanvas`

Comment: are you loading a big image in your second activity?

Comment: @DrilonBlakqori I am loading a large image on the second screen. I added largeHeap="true" to my manifest but that didn't do the trick. Ended up with the following error: `01-09 22:01:05.793 8974-9003/com.surrrge.consumer.surrrge E/EGL_emulation: tid 9003: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
`

Comment: remove that largeHeap. Try out the answer i just posted

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the new `OnClickListener`, it should be like this example :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. That resolved the build issue, in addition to the view not being resolved. I'm still having an issue with my app crashing though. Do I have the code in the right place?

Comment: @NickParsons post your crash log please

Comment: @NickParsons try to add `largeHeap = "true"` to your manifest, if this doesn't solve it create a new issue with the code where you draw your canvas

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this and on adding View.OnclickListner implements methods so the public void Onclick method is created and use your intent inside it or you can do as Ahmed said.

```
package com.example.consumer.example;
```

//your imports here

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
     button.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment everything in your DisplayListCanvas.java and see if the error still exist.

Answer (score 0):

To display big images you need an image loading library. You can try these ones:
[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)
[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)
They are pretty easy to use and work flawlessly.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I've heard good things about Picasso. Will it do for background images? That's the image I was having issues with.

Comment: You'll need to add an `ImageView` with height and width set to `match_parent` and use it like a background